# Computed Binding with Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

This is an excerpt of my codes:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <iron-ajax auto
    url="####"
    params=""
    handle-as="json"
    last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.Items]]">
      <div>                                                
        [[_formatDate(item.ID.N)]]
      </div>                                        
    </template>
 </template>
 ...
 <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'home-view',
        _formatDate: function(ID) {
            console.log("TEST");
            return "TEST";
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am getting this Console Warning:

```
[Warning] [dom-bind::_annotatedComputationEffect]: – "compute method `_formatDate` not defined" (data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,(fu…%0A, line 265, x10)
```

So it seems that I do not know how to define _formatDate correctly so that it is recognized by Polymer. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're correctly declaring and using `_formatDate()`.

The warning comes from `dom-bind`, which is intended only for bindings in `index.html`, not inside `dom-module`. You should remove the `is="dom-bind"` from your top template.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.6.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <home-view></home-view>

  <dom-module id="home-view">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
        <div>[[_formatDate(item)]]</div>
      </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      // For cross-browser compatibility, HTMLImports.whenReady()
      // needed in index.html only
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'home-view',
          properties: {
            items: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() { return ['hello', 'world']; }
            }
          },
          _formatDate: function(id) {
            console.log('id', id);
            return id;
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```